# Rails: What does 'type' do in xx_path(type: 'mark')?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A piece of code like this

```
<%= link_to 'find', xx_path(type: 'mark') %>
```

Anybody could tell me how to use type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'find', xx_path(type: 'mark') %>
```

Passing anything to a route helper in a key value pair will be passed in params.

You can access it in controller using `params[:type]` or `params["type"]`